# Add XSLT 2 schema to Visual Studio 2010 for intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, intellisense, xslt-2.0

I'd like to add the XSLT 2 schema to Visual Studio 2010 to provide intellisense. I've added the schema to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas (removing the XSLT 1 schema), but to no avail. The schema seems to have been parsed by Visual Studio, as I can hover my cursor over the namespace declaration in the stylesheet (xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform") and see the comments from the new schema, however, intellisense still refers to the XSLT 1 implementation. For example, the <xsl:function/> element has a warning that 'xsl:function is not yet available'.

Do I need to register the schema in some way? Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. If the XSLT 2.0 schema has imports then remove the `schemaLocation` attributes from those. Are you getting any schema related errors ?